# What am I understanding wrong about this simple asynchio example

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I can't wrap my head around how to use aynchio. Can you please just help me fix this issue. Assume I have some IO task which takes 8 seconds that I put in the coroutine task(). I want to run an infinite loop and perform this take every 5 seconds without blocking my code.

```
import asyncio


async def task():
    print('starting task')
    await asyncio.sleep(8)
    print('finished task')

async def main():
    count = 0
    while True:
        print(count)
        if count % 5 == 0:
            print('running task')
            await task()
        count += 1
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

asyncio.run(main())
```

From my understanding of the docs, when I perform `await` inside the `task` coroutine, it should go back to executing `main` but this does not happen. What am I doing wrong here? My output is

```
0
running task
starting task
finished task
1
2
3
4
5
running task
starting task
finished task
6
7
8
9
10
```

Comment: It doesn't go back to `main()`. It goes back to the event loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is you're awaiting the coroutine, which does what it says on the box:  It stops anything from proceeding until it completes (to say it doesn't go back to main isn't quite right either.  It does, just later than you wanted).  Spinning it out to another unawaited task will let it "run in the background"

```
import asyncio

async def task():
    print('starting task')
    await asyncio.sleep(8)
    print('finished task')

async def main():
    count = 0
    while True:
        print(count)
        if count % 5 == 0:
            print('running task')
            asyncio.create_task(task())
        count += 1
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

asyncio.run(main())
```

Gives me, which I think is what you want

```
0
running task
starting task
1
2
3
4
5
running task
starting task
6
7
finished task
8
9
10
running task
starting task
11
12
finished task
13
14
```

Comment: Thank you... I get this warning for the `create_task` that says `Coroutine 'create_task' is not awaited`. Does this matter? Why is it giving a warning and is it okay to leave like this?

Comment: I think you're fine for this example.  It basically says "nothing is waiting for this" and, for example, your program could terminate before that completed which is often not behavior folks want.  In a real scenario I would do something like save the task to a variable and await it later, or aggregate them in an array and use something like `asyncio.gather` to wait for all of them to complete later.

Comment: 'save the task to a variable and await it later' how do I do this? would you mind providing an example using my same goal from the OP? I have tried this already and I can't get it to work.